# how to know the app is closed or not when i have minimize the app and side swipe that app in codename one?

Tags: codenameone, minimize, close-application

i have install my app in android tablet.i have maintain the sessions for logged in users, for this purpose i want to know the app is closed or just minimized the app by the client.suppose if i have minimized the app and swipe that app (i.e closing).so,how to find the app is invoked exit Application or not on this scenario.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to Application LifeCycle. In CodenameOne, you have 4 hooks to manage lifecycle of your application. Here it is :

```
public void init(Object context) {}
public void start() {}
public void stop() {}
public void destroy() {}
```

**init()** is used when the App is launched (NOT resumed !).
**start()** is used when application come on foreground (After init, or after being minimized)
**stop()** is used when application goes to background (ie minimized)
**destroy()** is used when the OS kill the process (don't know if it's efficient on all platform at this time)

You can always find more information here ==> [CN1 developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/index.html#_application_lifecycle)